# Movie about creatures resembling antlions that crawl down people's throats and take them over

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens, horror

I saw a movie when I was younger, kind of like *Night of the Creeps*, *Slither*, and *The Hidden*. It had a monster/alien that looked like an antlion that crawled down your throat.  It may have been a 70's or 80's movie.

I can't remember a plot, but it was like any other "alien invasion"-type movie. I think it was in color. For some reason, the scene I can remember took place in a public restroom. The monster resembled an antlion that crawled down throats and took over the person.

I think I remember seeing it in the late '80s. It was set in the present day of that time frame. There were multiple creatures and multiple victims.

Comment: This is incredibly terse can you remember anything else that happens that you could [edit] in? In fact can you remember any of the plot or story to the film? What the characters looked like? Where it took place? etc.

Comment: In roughly what year did you see this movie? Was there only one creature, or several/lots of them? Was the victim you remember male or female? Did the movie have a present day setting, or a futuristic one?

Comment: I think i remember seeing it late 80's. it was set in the present day of that time frame.  there were multiple creatures. there were multiple victims

Comment: So not *[Starship Troopers 2](https://starshiptroopers.fandom.com/wiki/Control_Bug)*?

Comment: I can't help but think of the Star Trek: The Next Generation episode Conspiracy, but that was neither a movie nor set in the present day.

Comment: This is reminiscent of the [Ceti Eel](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Ceti_eel) from _Star Trek II: The Wrath of Khan_. Another possibility is the 1959 movie _[The Tingler](https://m.imdb.com/title/tt0053363/)_.